# Disabling the hover effect upon hovering over a bar in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, css, hover, google-visualization

I have a Google Charts timeline, and I'd like to disable to hover animation that happens whenever a bar is moused over. I also have click interactions with the bar, so I'd like to remove this hover animation without disabling my click interactions. Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable the tooltip, without affecting the `'select'` event

by using the [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#configuration-options) --> `tooltip.trigger: 'none'`

**EDIT**

to prevent the bars from changing colors *on hover*

save a reference to the original bar when the `'ready'` event fires
the bars will be `rect` elements, with an `x` attribute greater than `0`

when an original bar is *hovered over*, a new bar is created
it will be the last `rect` in the list

so change the `'fill'` color of the new bar,
using the `row` reference from the event or selection,
back to the reference saved

using `'onmouseover'` and `'select'` events

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

    // save original colors
    var origColors = [];
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      bars = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(bars, function(bar, index) {
        if (parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('x')) > 0) {
          origColors.push(bar.getAttribute('fill'));
        }
      });
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      var selection = chart.getSelection();
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        // set original color
        var bars = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
        bars[bars.length - 1].setAttribute('fill', origColors[selection[0].row]);
      }
      document.getElementById('msg_div').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(chart.getSelection());
    });
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (e) {
      // set original color
      var bars = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
      bars[bars.length - 1].setAttribute('fill', origColors[e.row]);
    });

    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'none'
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
<div id="msg_div"></div>
```

Comment: I already have the tooltip disabled, I want the hover animation to be disabled.

Comment: see __EDIT__ to above answer, only way I know would be to modify the chart when `onmouseover` and `select` fires